# Why using jQuery at the server side with node?

Tags: jquery, node.js, server

I have been seeing people on overflow using jquery+jsdom to use jQuery at the server side. I am building my application with ExpressJS for the server side and angularJS for the client side. I was thinking using jQuery to do http request but eventually decided to use `request` module. I am wondering what would be the reason for using jQuery at the server side? Is there any valid cases to justify that?

Comment: Usually is for DOM manipulation, rather than requests and whatnot. So things like `$("div").each(...)`.

Comment: Shouldn't that be done at the client side? I am trying to understand if there's a valid reason to use jquery at the server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try jQuery on server side if you are doing page scraping. I used [Cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) for web page scraping on Server side and provided an API based on the same.

Also websites like Yodlee use [page scrapping on server side](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1537825) for financial data integration.